# OSX 10.10.5 Printing Wrong Sized Paper

Tags: macos, printing

We have a mac on yosemite 10.10.5 that was printing to a canon printer just fine up until the other day. No matter what we do with a 7x9.5 document, the canon printer gets the job and is complaining because it doesn't have size b5 paper. The thing is, we are telling it to print on us letter which is what it should be printing on. That is what the computer is set to for default and when we are on the print options page we have double checked over and over again that nothing is set wrong.

I have removed the printer, deleted the driver, restarted the computer, then reinstalled the driver and nothing has worked.

If we send the document to a neighboring Mac computer it prints just fine from there with the exact same settings.

Are there preference files or something for printers or acrobat that I can reset?

Answer (score 0):

Your steps look solid, so it might be time for the reset you seek to try to set up the drivers and configurations from scratch.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/reset-mac-printing-system-solve-a-problem-mh14001/mac

There are PDE and the “make a second queue before you delete the first queue” tricks covered here that might be worth trying as well.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/solve-printing-problems-on-mac-mh14002/mac